# Jms Configuration Ready Api 2.2

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, ready-api

i am trying to manually configure JMS in Ready API 2.2 . I want to use Apache ActiveMQ , for that i need valid inputs for :

```
Initial Context Class 
Provider Url 
Connection Factory JNDI name
```

I have checked many sources , but i am not getting exact values for these . Can anyone provide them. And what are basic Jar files required ?

Comment: Which ActiveMQ broker are you using?

Comment: are you talking about the jar? I have added "activemq-all-5.2.0" jar in lib folder of ready api .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html) on this subject.  It should answer most if not all your questions.